# Como matar, remover ou não inicializar o banco master do SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

Acordei pela manhã e dei um "Executar" em cima do banco "`cotacao`", banco que eu estou trabalhando no momento. Aí entrou a tela de login e quando eu *logei* o banco que recebeu as tabelas foi o *master* e não o "`cotacao`". No provedor que hospedo meu site e banco, ele não entra. Quando eu logo, é sempre meu banco.

Tem como fazer isso em minha máquina? Escolher um banco padrão e será sempre ele que vai aparecer quando me logar. Como eu faço isso?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Se você tiver privilégio pode fazer isto:

```
ALTER LOGIN pnet WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = meudb
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/DML/AlterLogin.sql).